# Under AIX 5.2-6.1 + C program env, how to write code similar to CORE_NOSHM = true?

Tags: aix, core-file

I'am writing a program in C under AIX env, to attach to a BIG IPC shared memory segment.
Sometimes it may generate a huge coredump, I found "export CORE_NOSHM = true" can filter shared memory in corefile, 
but how can I specify this in my C code?

Answer (score 0):

Use putenv or setenv.

```
setenv ("CORE_NOSHM", "true", 1);
```

Comment: Yes, I tried putenv in the program, but it is useless, it seems the env has to be set before starting my program.

Comment: Guess this answers your question: it has to be set before staring your program. In a launcher-script, for example: `export CORE_NOSHM=true; exec binary_executable "$@"`